# Spark show logged in user

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, spark-view-engine

How do I show the username of the person logged in within a Spark View?

The default MVC view engine had a Page object that you could get the info from.

How would I do that in spark?

I know that I could put the info into the viewdata dictionary, which is probably the best, but I don't want to have to write

```
ViewData["User"] = myUser;
```

before I return from EVERY action method.

I'd like some feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for making me look at the properties again.

I found the user object in

```
Context.User
```

within the Spark View. It doesn't have a page object, but it does have what I need. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Page.User:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.user%28v=VS.100%29.aspx